# remove hidden newlines from file in bash

Tags: bash

I am creating a file with the output of a ps command as follows.

```
ps aux | grep ^apache | grep sbin/[h]ttpd | awk '{print $2" "$6}' > /root/psfile.tmp
```

when you look at the file it reads as the following.

```
[root@testserver ~]# tail /root/psfile.tmp
16795 3184
16796 3148
16797 3148
16799 3148
16800 3148
16801 3148
16802 3148
16803 3148 
16804 3148
16805 3148
```

However, when I try to process this within a for loop, it is reading one line as two lines... eg...

```
for x in $(tail /root/psfile.tmp.test);do echo $x;done
16795
3184
16796
3148
16797
3148
16799
3148
16800
3148
16801
3148
16802
3148
16803
3148
16804
3148
16805
3148
```

I need the for iteration to show both numbers on one line...  why is it doing this and how can I get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: There aren't "hidden newlines" in the file. Instead, `for` is splitting by whitespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while read one two
do
    echo "one: $one"
    echo "two: $two"
done < psfile.tmp.test
```

or

```
while read line
do
    echo "line: $line"
done < psfile.tmp.test
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `IFS=$'\n'` before you run the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
tail /root/psfile.tmp.test | while read -r a b ; do
  echo "a: $a b: $b"
done
```

Keep your code as-is and set `IFS` to `$'\n'` to make the for loop split on new-lines only - by default, it splits on any whitespace.